# Only change content(body) by clicking different button In HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the content when I click the button, but I don't know how to do this in HTML and CSS. Do I need to do this with another web development programming(JS..)?

I have a button1 and body(content is Heeelooo), but if i click button2 it will only change content(body).

HTML

```
.body
    {
    //position: absolute;
        opacity:0.9;
    //position: relative;
        margin-left: 250px;
        //margin-top: 0px;
        width:800px;
        height:1200px;
        background-color:gray;
        box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px blue;
        border-radius:25px;
        border:2px solid #a1a1a1;

    }

a.button {
    width:60px;
    height:20px;
    margin-left: 260px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    outline: none;
    color:white;
    background:#383838 ;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-color:white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: bold 14px/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

CSS

```
<div class="button">BUTTON 1</a>
</div>

<div  class="food">BUTTON 2</a>
</div>


<div class="body">Helloooooooo</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Show us the code ... that what you have tried to do this and tell us where you find difficulty .. or else its not a question. its like do it for me question. That's why you are getting -1

Comment: Post updated. I don't know how to do if i click button2, it only changes content info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use Javascript, attach a click event handler to the buttons that will change out the appropriate content. [Here is an article](http://www.cssnewbie.com/showhide-content-css-javascript/#.U34xpa1dVZ4)

Given the update to your code, I would recommend using jQuery. jQuery will allow you to do the following:

```
$('.button').on('click', function () {
    $('.body').html('New content.');
});
$('.food').on('click', function () {
    $('.body').html('Some other stuff.');
});
```